# Could running a Heroku one-off dyno as `:detached` cause it to consume more memory?

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I run my management command in a detached one-off dyno, it exceeds the memory quota almost immediately. When I run non-detached, it works perfectly. I would like some insight as to how that could possibly be. Any answer that points to any documentation on this phenomenon would be amazing.

This is for a Python management command (`addfeederpolygons`) that I estimate to use a few hundred megabytes of memory, as it does some intensive spatial joins with geodjango.

Are there ways that the underlying code could perform differently in a detached one-off dyno vs. a non-detached one-off dyno?

I expect the results to be the same, regardless of whether or not the dyno is running detached. But here is the actual output:

**When running un-detached**

```
$ heroku run -a kevala-api-stage python manage.py addfeederpolygons --geography 25 --overwrite
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.0.33 to 7.19.3
Running python manage.py addfeederpolygons --geography 25 --overwrite on ⬢ kevala-api-stage... up, run.8817 (Standard-1X)
initialized redis cache
Imported all multipolygon data for 328922
Imported all multipolygon data for 329602
...etc...
```

this does not crash, and runs **much** faster than the other scenario...

**When running detached**

```
$ heroku run:detached -a kevala-api-stage python manage.py addfeederpolygons --geography 25 --overwrite
$ heroku logs --app kevala-api-stage --dyno run.5051 -n 1500
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.0.33 to 7.19.3
2019-01-30T19:23:10.894495+00:00 heroku[run.5051]: State changed from starting to up
2019-01-30T19:23:19.578170+00:00 app[run.5051]: initialized redis cache
2019-01-30T19:23:56.311511+00:00 heroku[run.5051]: Process running mem=553M(108.1%)
2019-01-30T19:23:56.311732+00:00 heroku[run.5051]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2019-01-30T19:24:00.700959+00:00 app[run.5051]: Imported all multipolygon data for 328922
2019-01-30T19:24:03.325782+00:00 app[run.5051]: Imported all multipolygon data for 329602
...etc...
eventually fails with R15
```

Comment: Do you think that since the detached dyno outputs to logs instead of the console, the writestream would be eating enough memory to cause your issue? Just a thought. Also, you may want to try updating Heroku?

Comment: it's possible. it logs a lot of info. do you know of a way to suppress output?

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. Let me look into it...

Answer (score 2):

So, I lost the ability to comment for the moment, so I am kind of forced to write out an answer. Good news is, I think what you want to do is set up a [Log Drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains#removing-drains) to compensate for the memory leaks and/or bottlenecking you're experiencing.

If you don't mind, could I also see one of the logs in question (Pastebin?). I would like to see exactly what's going on, that would probably help.

Comment: @Teddy Ward Did you try using the log drain?

Comment: I tried, but it seems like since the `drains` command does not take a `--dyno` flag, I would have to set up a log drain for the whole app, which I don't think I can do in my organization. Also, I'm not sure if creating a log drain stops it from logging in memory. seems like it's more additive. Anyway, I'm experimenting with making the underlying code less noisy, and hoping that helps.